# adding to a column in a df in pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file that I am turning into a pandas dataframe. One of the columns `a` is mostly filled with numbers and occasionally filled with zeros. I would like to make a new column `e` that is the number in column `a+500`, EXCEPT if there is a `0` in that row for the `a` column. In those cases it should just stay `0`. Or I guess it would also work if column `e` was `a+500`, and then all of the cases in `e` that were just `500` were turned into zero. Any help would be great, I'm new to using pandas/python.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Your question is too broad as is. Please read [ask] and start trying yourself. Once you get stuck, ask here providing a [MCVE]! Thank you!

Comment: I disagree with @jkalden as the question is rather specific but the title is very misleading. Please edit your title to something more specific like "adding value to a column in a df in pandas python depending on another columns value". I agree you should add a minimal example that at least shows input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df['new_a'] = df['a'].astype('int').map(lambda x: x+500 if x != 0 else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Example data frame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 0, 200], 'b': [200, 500, 0]})
>>> df
     a    b
0  100  200
1    0  500
2  200    0
```

### Solution

You can use [where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for fast generation of your column:

```
>>> df['e'] = df['a'].where(df['a'] == 0, df['a'] + 500)
>>> df
     a    b    e
0  100  200  600
1    0  500    0
2  200    0  700
```

### Performance

For a data frame with three million rows:

```
n = int(1e6)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [100, 0, 200] * n, 'b': [200, 500, 0] * n})
```

using apply (as suggested in another answer here) is pretty slow:

```
%timeit df['new_a'] = df['a'].astype('int').map(lambda x: x+500 if x != 0 else 0)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.5 s per loop
```

compared to using `where()`:

```
%timeit df['e'] = df['a'].where(df['a'] == 0, df['a'] + 500)
10 loops, best of 3: 90.9 ms per loop
```

It is about 28 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to write a function and use `pd.apply` like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1]})
def add500ifnot0(c):
    if c == 0:
        return c
    else:
        return c + 500
df['e'] = df['a'].apply(add500ifnot0)
df
```